# Preferred way to customize UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am trying to customize a UITableViewCell after some initial study it seems I can customize the UITableViewCell in two ways

Option 1:

As explained in the TableViewCell iOS [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) I can add custom label using storyboard and specify UI constraint if any using the interface builder and then the access the label from code using viewWithTag as explained below

```
label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
label.text = @"something"
```

Option 2:

I can create a custom xib file and design the table cell using interface builder and specify UI constraint if any and have a custom class inherited from UITableViewCell with the all the label as property wired to corresponding label using interface builder and use the following code to create UITableViewCell based on the xib

```
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustommCell" bundle:nil]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"resuseIdentifier"];
MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier"];
MyCustomTableViewCell.myCustomLabel.text = @"something";
```

I agree that the second option is bit time consuming compared to the first option but it yields me the following advantage over the first option:

- I can reuse it for similarly styled UITableViewCell
- Better readability compared to the option 1
- Better separation of concern, UITableViewController doesn't have to worry how the cell is laid out in interface builder instead its properly delegated to separate xib file

In spite of above advantage I'm more worried why Apple documentation didn't choose the second option when explaining how to customize UITableViewCell? Am I missing something obvious here? or is there any performance issue with the second approach compared to the first one?

Comment: You can use a subclass of `UITableViewCell` in a storyboard, so your question sets up a false choice. The choice isn't between using a nib or storyboard, it's between subclassing or not subclassing.

Comment: @jlehr its not between subclassing or not subclassing, its between nib or storyboard as both offers rich way to layout the label (using constraint and specifying styles)

Comment: You can do the same thing in a storyboard, so how is the choice between a storyboard and a nib?

Comment: You can also do everything programmatically without IB at all (including constraints). It just comes down to your preference.

Comment: @jlehr in storyboard you are designing the entire ViewController whereas in nib I'm just creating my own custom UITableViewCell and defining its layout and then using it, so its clearly a choice between storyboard and nib

Comment: @LyricalPanda I agree all these can be done with code, storyboard and nib file but my question is whats the trade off and when to use what? Is there any performance related choice among them?

Answer (score 0):

Far be it from me to state why something is or is not in the Apple Documentation, but from my speculation, one reason that Option 2 is not explicitly specified in the documentation is that you can actually set this up directly in storyboard's display of the UITableView, as a prototype cell. This is basically a GUI inline of the nib UITableViewCell, and it will properly set up all those methods you described in Option 2 automatically so that you do not need to call any of them.